# Variables from url don't exist in $_GET array

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, request, get

I'm using October cms.

Have a url: https://my-site.ru/search?q=test, it doesn't matter if I write it myself, or get by form, on that page var_dump($_GET) display this: array(0) { }.

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] displays uri with parameter /search?q=test.

But if I use post method of the form, everything ok.

var_dump is on the top of /index.php.

Comment: You aren't supposed to use $_GET array in October cms

Comment: Probably because this rewrites `/search` to the index.php, but doesn't append the original query string while doing so.